# XCode UIView on top of TableView first Cell origin

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewController` which has a `UITableView` and inside there, there is an `UIView` and a **Prototype Cell** under the UIView.

The content of the `UIView` is Dynamic so i want to change the origin (y) of the first row dynamic.

When I change the `UIView` frame and bounds

```
self.albumView.bounds=CGRectMake(0,0,self.albumView.frame.size.width, self.albumView.frame.size.height+100);
self.albumView.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,self.albumView.frame.size.width, self.albumView.frame.size.height+100);
```

the UIView overlaps and Hides the rows (i can see only the header)

**BUT** when I wrote the same code on 
`(void)viewWillAppear`
it works fine but the problem is that I don't know the height because I have not yet received the data from the request.

I tried

```
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
[self.tableView setNeedsDisplay];
```

but nothing seems to work. How can I fix this?

I am adding a snap from my TableViewController layout

http://preview.otherlap.com/snap.png
(i cannot add image because am i new user so there is a link)

The height of the UIView is dynamic according to json data. 
All i want is to change the origin (y) position of the first row of the table.

Here a sample code

```
    -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
         //self.albumView.bounds=CGRectMake(0,0,self.albumView.frame.size.width,self.albumView.frame.size.height+100);
       //self.albumView.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,self.albumView.frame.size.width,self.albumView.frame.size.height+100);
    }
     - (void)viewDidLoad
 {

    [super viewDidLoad];
     ...load some data from server
 }
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{

    [jsonData setLength:0];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
    [jsonData appendData:data];

}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
 self.albumView.bounds=CGRectMake(0,0,self.albumView.frame.size.width,self.albumView.frame.size.height+dynamicHeight);  self.albumView.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,self.albumView.frame.size.width,self.albumView.frame.size.height+dynamicHeight);
}
```

if i set the UIView height on ViewWillAppear it move the origin of the first cell correctly. if i set the height on connectionDidFinishLoad it overlaps the Cells.

EDIT:
Found the answer
ok i found the answer bymyself..

Adding a UiView on top of a TableView on a StoryBoard it automatically make it its tableHeaderView

So the solution was that

```
CGRect newFrame = self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame;
newFrame.size.height = DynamicHeight;
self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame = newFrame;
[self.tableView setTableHeaderView:self.tableView.tableHeaderView];
```

Comment: This question doesn't seem to have anything to do with Xcode.

Comment: mate, you'll need to show some code so we can get a better understanding of what your problem is.

Comment: i posted some code. i m using XCode.

Answer (score -1):

`setNeedsLayout` means that `- (void)layoutSubviews` methods needs to be called. Therefore you need to put your resizing code in `- (void)layoutSubviews` method.

Comment: That is not true. `setNeedsDisplay` means that `drawRect:` needs to be called. There is also a method `setNeedsLayout`.

Comment: My mistake, set needs layout is what I meant.